# Hover:scale-125 not working on images with Tailwind CSS

Tags: angular, image, hover, scale, tailwind-css

I have a row of images that I want to enlarge as I hover over them. The documentation seems pretty simple, but it's not working for some reason. This is what I'm doing on each image:

```
        class="inline h-64 hover:scale-125"
        [src]="'assets/images/teaching/custom-craftsmanship.jpg'"
      />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks right, I tested it here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/W7tAauFPb3?layout=horizontal . Maybe the problem is on the parent element.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add the "transform" class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In order to fit in your scaled image within a fixed frame, you have to add "overflow-hidden" to your parent element.

An example below shows an image is scaled to 110% during hover and still fit within the parent frame.

```
<div className="overflow-hidden">
   <img className="... hover:scale-110">
      ...
   </img>
</div>
```